# handle event collapse bar on borderlayout zk

Tags: java, layout, zk

I am developing an ERP in Java and ZK.

I have a `borderlayout` where the north contains the panel with some filters.

I want to make the North collapsible.

If I hit the arrow to collapse it or open it, it works fine, but if I press it instead on the bar, it does not open properly but only preview.

Can i disable this feature? Can I handle the click event on the bar?

**Java:**

```
North north = new North();
m_mainLayout.appendChild(north);
north.setHflex("1");
north.setCollapsible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that can help you. Some of them might be quite new, as they are not well documented and not available in my Eclipse's autocomplete in zul.

First of all: **slide** - There is a `setSlide(boolean)` on the layout regions, and an [`onSlide` event](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/SlideEvent.html) you can listen to when clicking the bar, but not the button.

Second, there is a **[library property](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Layouts/Borderlayout#Configure_to_Disable_the_Animation_Effects_as_Default)** to turn off the collapse animation:

```
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zul.borderlayout.animation.disabed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</library-property>
```

You can specify it in `zk.xml` to see whether your case works better with or without animation (in my mini example it worked better without animation).

Third, and most important, add this **style** which will make the whole bar behave like the button:

```
<style>
    .z-north-collapsed>.z-borderlayout-icon {
        top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
    }
    .z-north-collapsed>.z-borderlayout-icon::before {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

This is only for `north`, you might want to make it a bit more general for the other regions. I found that making the button bigger and leaving all the animation/event handling/component replacement to zk looks and works best.

---

**Example:**

```
<style>
    .z-north-collapsed>.z-borderlayout-icon {
        top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
    }
    .z-north-collapsed>.z-borderlayout-icon::before {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<borderlayout>
    <north splittable="true" collapsible="true" >
        <button label="hello" />
    </north>
    <center>
        <textbox value="world" />
    </center>
</borderlayout>
```